# Z3 using goals and tactics

Tags: c, z3

I am using Z3 with C-API. I am trying to understand how to understand how to use the tactics and goal in C-API. I checked in the examples of Z3, but could not find one that suits me.

I have my C-API psuedo-code as below -

```
contextId = mk_context();
solverId = Z3_mk_solver(contextId);
Z3_solver_inc_ref(contextId, solverId);
... 
then some assertions like x > 0, y > 0 and so on..
...
// now comes the final goal
mygoal = Z3_mk_less_than(contextId, ...) //  x < 50
Z3_solver_assert (contextId, solverId, mygoal)
...
// finally   check
Z3_solver_check(contextId, solverId)
Z3_reset_memory();
Z3_del_context(contextId);
Z3_solver_dec_ref(contextId, solverId);
```

Now I want to apply some tactics to the mygoal.
However, I am not able to get how exactly the C-API should follow.
I checked the documentation, but could not find an example doing this.

What I tried is to use `Z3_goal_assert ();` API. But it didn't work somehow.
Could someone give me a simple example with C-API?

UPDATE : I tried the following C-Code, but it doesn't work.
At the function call `Z3_tactic_apply()`, the solver throws an error like this -

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
```

Piece of Code :

```
goalId = Z3_mk_goal();      
Z3_goal_inc_ref(context, goalId);

assertionVector = Z3_solver_get_assertions (context, solver);
int vectorSize = Z3_ast_vector_size(assertionVector);

for(int i=0;i<vectorSize;i++)       
    Z3_goal_assert(context, goalId, Z3_ast_vector_get(context, assertionVector, i));

Z3_goal_assert(context, goalId, Z3_mk_eq(context, totalProcDecl, Z3_mk_int(context, numProcessors, int_sort)));
Z3_goal_assert(context, goalId, Z3_mk_eq(contextlatencyDecl, Z3_mk_int(context, latencyConstraint, int_sort)));

// This is what I am trying to apply
// (check-sat-using (then (! simplify :arith-lhs true) solve-eqs lia2pb pb2bv bit-blast sat))

tactic0 = Z3_mk_tactic (context, "simplify");
Z3_tactic_inc_ref (context,tactic0);

tactic1 = Z3_mk_tactic (context, "solve-eqs");
Z3_tactic_inc_ref (context, tactic1);

tactic2 = Z3_mk_tactic (context, "lia2pb");
Z3_tactic_inc_ref (context, tactic2);

tactic3 = Z3_mk_tactic (context, "pb2bv");
Z3_tactic_inc_ref (context, tactic3);

tactic4 = Z3_mk_tactic (context, "bit-blast");
Z3_tactic_inc_ref (context, tactic4);

tactic5 = Z3_mk_tactic (context, "sat");
Z3_tactic_inc_ref (context, tactic5);

temp = Z3_tactic_and_then (context, tactic0, tactic1);
temp = Z3_tactic_and_then (context, temp, tactic2);
temp = Z3_tactic_and_then (context, temp, tactic3);
temp = Z3_tactic_and_then (context, temp, tactic4);
temp = Z3_tactic_and_then (context, temp, tactic5);

result = Z3_tactic_apply (context, temp, goalId);
printf("Result : %s\n", Z3_apply_result_to_string (context, result));

// Finished Solving.
Z3_goal_dec_ref (context, goalId);
Z3_tactic_dec_ref (context, tactic0);
Z3_tactic_dec_ref (context, tactic1);
Z3_tactic_dec_ref (context, tactic2);
Z3_tactic_dec_ref (context, tactic3);
Z3_tactic_dec_ref (context, tactic4);
Z3_tactic_dec_ref (context, tactic5);
```

I also tried one more option to add parameter to simplify tactic.

```
tactic0_without_param = Z3_mk_tactic (context, "simplify");
Z3_tactic_inc_ref (context,tactic0_without_param);

paramsId = Z3_mk_params(context);
Z3_params_inc_ref(context, paramsId);
Z3_params_set_bool (context, p, paramsId, Z3_mk_string_symbol(context, ":arith-lhs"), true);
tactic0 = Z3_tactic_using_params (context, tactic0, paramsId);
```

But again doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Z3 4.x comes with C++ header files that makes the Z3 C API much easier to use (file `include/z3++.h`).
It also has an example based on C++ (file `examples/c++/example.cpp`). This file contains many examples  using tactic objects.

That being said, tactics should be applied to Goals. For convenience, we also provide an API that creates a solver from a tactic `Z3_mk_solver_from_tactic`. The solver object returned by this API will tries to solve a satisfiability query using the given tactic.

Comment: suppose I have some assertions. I would like to solve the same sometimes with and sometimes without tactic. How exactly should I achieve this? Can I use the same solver for both of them?

Comment: Yes, we can convert the assertions in a `Solver` object into a `Goal` object. Here is an example on how to do it: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/4j5
After we convert it into a `Goal` object, we can solve it using tactics.

Comment: Dear Leo, I added a C code which possibly tries to do the same thing as your python code. But it doesn't work; could you please help me out with it? Thanks.

Comment: The code in your question has several missing `Z3_*_inc_ref` calls. In principle, you have to invoke this kind of API for every object returned by Z3. The error you get is due to memory access violation. I strongly suggest you use the C++ wrapper objects in `include/z3++.h`. They will automatically manage the reference counters for you. The examples in `examples/c++/example.cpp` are also very helpful, and illustrate how to use this wrapper. Another option is the .Net or Python Z3 APIs.

Comment: I am calling Z3 from Java using JNI API. So I think, for me switching to C++ API will take some time. Further, I am not so sure, if that will solve the problem?

Comment: The `Z3_tactic_apply` API returns `Z3_apply_result`. When converted and printed to string, it says `false`. Does it mean that it is `UNSAT`? Also is there any equivalent in C-API for `check-sat-using` ? Thanks !

Comment: I see. If you are using Z3 from Java, then using the C++ API will not help much. I think managing the reference counters manually is difficult. Is it possible to use an approach similar to the one used in the Python wrapper API for Z3. The source code of the python wrapper API is included in the Z3 distribution (directory `python`).

Comment: Regarding `Z3_apply_result` `to_string` API, it returns a string starting with `(goals`. Then, it includes the string representation of each subgoal. If one goal is unsatisfiable, then it will be printed as `false`.

Comment: Regarding `check-sat-using`, you can use the API `Z3_mk_solver_from_tactic` to convert a tactic into a `Z3_solver` object. That is how `check-sat-using` is implemented.